# Beginner Java Q

Tags: java

Just started learning Java, how can I change this so that it actually outputs `lamp1.printStates` and `lamp2.printStates?` When I run it, it just returns that it built successfully but nothing else.

```
 package lamps;

    public class Lamps {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        class Lamp {
            int on = 0;
            int brightness = 0;

            void changeOn(int newValue) {
                on = newValue;
        }

            void changeBrightness(int newValue) {
                brightness = newValue;
        }

            void printStates() {
                System.out.println("On/Off:" + on + 
                        " brightness:" + brightness);

        }
    }

    class CreateLamps {
        public void main(String[] args) {
           Lamp lamp1 = new Lamp();
           Lamp lamp2 = new Lamp();

           lamp1.changeOn(1);
           lamp1.changeBrightness(4);
           lamp1.printStates();

           lamp2.changeOn(1);
           lamp2.changeBrightness(6);
           lamp2.changeBrightness(4);
           lamp2.changeOn(0);
           lamp2.changeBrightness(0);
           lamp2.printStates();
    }


   }
  }
 }
```

Comment: You may be building your project without running it. What IDE are you using (eg eclipse, Netbeans)?

Comment: Netbeans, I have been running the project though.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is quite odd and creating a class to "create lamps" is very bad practice, but nevertheless, let's look at the problem at hand.

When your program is being run, the `main` method of `Lamps` is being executed, but not the `main` method of `CreateLamps`. You need to call that method yourself. You could do that by putting `new CreateLamps(args)` in your `main` method in `Lamps`.

But still, I strongly advice against the structure of your program.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have some basic misconceptions about how to best structure your classes.

Typically, a class looks like this:

```
public class MyClass {
    public MyClass() {
        // constructor code
    }

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
        myClass.doStuff();
    }

    public void doStuff() {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

What you have is a mishmash of inner classes that are going to be a pain to work with and are  not how you want to start this adventure.

Answer (score 0):

You've got classes and main methods all intermingled.  You need one class, `Lamp`, and a static main method in that class can test things out for you.  Something like this perhaps (I didn't try to compile it.)

I also took the liberty of changing on the "on/off" variable to a boolean.

```
package lamps;

public class Lamp {

   private boolean on = 0;
   private int brightness = 0;

   public void changeOn(boolean newValue) {
       on = newValue;
   }

   public void changeBrightness(int newValue) {
       brightness = newValue;
   }

   public void printStates() {
       System.out.println("On:" + on + 
             " brightness:" + brightness);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Lamp lamp1 = new Lamp();
       Lamp lamp2 = new Lamp();

       lamp1.changeOn(true);
       lamp1.changeBrightness(4);
       lamp1.printStates();

       lamp2.changeOn(true);
       lamp2.changeBrightness(6);
       lamp2.changeBrightness(4);
       lamp2.changeOn(false);
       lamp2.changeBrightness(0);
       lamp2.printStates();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the important concept you are a little confused on here is what classes, methods, and fields are. Fields define data. methods define behavior to be applied to data (or cause some other effect). Classes group data (fields) with behavior (methods). Classes also perform encapsulation, which enables us to make data and methods private to a particular class, only available to the package the class belongs to (that is the default) or publicly available to any other class.

In this case you really only need one class. You can let the main method do most of the work. You can also keep those few methods you defined for setting field values and printing to System.out. You should make your methods and fields private unless you intend on allowing other classes to access them. Always use the highest level of privacy possible. It makes it possible for others to distinguish between your class's public API and the methods and fields  that are only meant to be used internally.

```
public class Lamp {
    private int on = 0;
    private int brightness = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Lamp lamp1 = new Lamp();
        Lamp lamp2 = new Lamp();

        lamp1.changeOn(1);
        lamp1.changeBrightness(4);
        lamp1.printStates();

        lamp2.changeOn(1);
        lamp2.changeBrightness(6);
        lamp2.changeBrightness(4);
        lamp2.changeOn(0);
        lamp2.changeBrightness(0);
        lamp2.printStates();
    }

    public void changeOn(int newValue) {
        on = newValue;
    }

    public void changeBrightness(int newValue) {
        brightness = newValue;
    }

// maybe you don't want other classes to be able to print the state so make this method private
    private void printStates() {
         System.out.println("On/Off:" + on + " brightness:" + brightness);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know what your problem is. If you want to display a variable, you have to use the method:

```
System.out.printf("");
```

So try this:

```
package lamps;

public class Lamps {

public static void main(String[] args) {

        int on = 0;
        int brightness = 0;

        void changeOn(int newValue) {
            on = newValue;
    }

        void changeBrightness(int newValue) {
            brightness = newValue;
    }

        void printStates() {
            System.out.printf("On/Off: %d brightness %d"on,brightness);


    }
}

    public void CreateLamps() {
       Lamp lamp1 = new Lamp();
       Lamp lamp2 = new Lamp();

       lamp1.changeOn(1);
       lamp1.changeBrightness(4);
       lamp1.printStates();

       lamp2.changeOn(1);
       lamp2.changeBrightness(6);
       lamp2.changeBrightness(4);
       lamp2.changeOn(0);
       lamp2.changeBrightness(0);
       lamp2.printStates();
}


    }
```

That should do it. 
Oh and also, You don't need 3 classes. Just create the method not the CreateLamps class.

Answer (score 0):

Structuring your classes will help you avoid confusion in the future. Using a beginner-friendly platform like NetBeans can help you do that. Netbeans has a feature that creates your main class for you. The main class in your program should initialize a class and then call the methods in that class you want to use, so shoot for something like this:

```
public void main(String[] args) {
    LampMethods lamp1 = new LampMehods();

    lamp1.changeOn(1);
    lamp1.changeBrightness(4);
    lamp1.printStates();
}
```

Then I recommend creating a new class (a different file that is still in the same package) to put all your methods in, maybe call it "LampMethods". This way the structure is black and white. Main is for calling methods and LampMethods is where you store those methods.